# Angular ngif template ref

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-forms, angular-template

I have a ngif - else condition to display either `#input1` or `#input2`.

Then a set of fields `#fieldset` wrapped in a ngif with the condition that either `#input1` or  `#input2` have a value using template-references.

This fails as [ng-if creates its own subtemplate](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19316), "hiding" `#input1` and `#input2`.

I don't want to repeat `#fieldset` inside the if and else block.
Can I do this without creating a new component containing the fields in `#fieldset`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventhough the approach suggested by @ashfaq.p is feasible, I believe it introduces too much complexity as the fields in `#fieldset` impact the validity of the form.

A simpler solution is a component method as recommended in the Angular docs in order to keep template expressions simple.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directive with the fieldsets, and then use the directive in both `if` and `else` section. That way, you will not be repeating the code.